# How to get all the function name from import file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `bundle.ts` file with a list of imports, for example:

```
import { addEvent } from './event/add.post';
import { removeEvent } from './event/remove.post';
import { updateEvent } from './event/update.post';
```

In another script, I like to loop through to get all the functions from `bundle.ts`

Is that possible?

Comment: `import * as bundle from './bundle.ts`

Comment: @Konrad script have no idea what the function name in bundle.ts

Answer (score -1):

If this is the only thing in the file you could do:

```
// file one: index.ts
export { addEvent } from './event/add.post';
export { removeEvent } from './event/remove.post';
export { updateEvent } from './event/update.post';
```

Then in another file:

```
import * as Whatever from './index.ts'

Whatever.addEvent(...)
```

Comment: another script is unware of function name like addEvent

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I was mainly pointing out the `export` part in the first file